# How to find max value in range based on certain conditions?

Tags: excel, vba

I have a sheet with a list of football matches and associated data. Each week I download new match data from a website, select all the new matches and add these rows to the sheet and then copy a few formulas down from columns that are only in my sheet and not part of the downloaded sheet.

I've built the below code for the data import by stitching together posts from here and other forums:

```
Sub FD_new()

Dim rngLeague As Range
Dim cell As Range
Dim copiedRange As Range
Dim r As Integer
Dim LastRowSrc As Long
Dim LastRowDestA As Long
Dim DestWS As Worksheet
Dim DestWB As Workbook
Dim MaxDate As long

Set DestWB = Workbooks("Master Sheet")
Set DestWS = DestWB.Worksheets("Sheet1")

MaxDate = DateValue("03/03/2019")

    'Build selected range to copy from dowload sheet
    LastRowSrc = Cells(Rows.Count, "A").End(xlUp).Row

    r = 0

    Set rngLeague = Range("C2:C" & LastRowSrc)

    For Each cell In rngLeague
        If DateValue(cell) > MaxDate Then
            If r = 0 Then
                Set copiedRange = Range(cell.Offset(0, -2), cell.Offset(0, 11))
                r = 1
            Else
                Set copiedRange = Union(copiedRange, Range(cell.Offset(0, -2), cell.Offset(0, 11)))
            End If
        End If
    Next cell

    'Copy and paste range once finished
    If r = 1 Then

        LastRowDestA = DestWS.Cells(Rows.Count, "A").End(xlUp).Row

        copiedRange.Copy DestWS.Range("A" & LastRowDestA + 1)

    End If

End Sub
```

However, where it gets complicated is that the download sheet sometimes doesn't have the latest data for all leagues - some are updated on a daily basis, some every 2-3 days. This means in manual mode I have to check my master sheet for the most recent match date for each league, go to the download sheet, select all the matches for this league that are after this date and copy across. Consequently I can't just use one MaxDate (as in above code).

So I think I need to update my code to:
- identify the most recent match date by league in the master sheet
- identify all the most recent matches for that league in the download sheet
- copy these across to the master sheet
- repeat for all the leagues

Of course there may be a simpler way to do it!

I think I need to create an array (or arrays) of leagues and dates, but if I'm honest I got totally confused.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

My suggestion is to create a `Dictionary` from your existing data in order to check if the "new" data being scanned is truly new or is a repeat of data you already have. ***This is a non-working example (because I don't have your database columns), but it illustrates the method.***

First, in the the VBE menu go to Tools-->References... and add the "Microsoft Scripting Runtime" library to your project.

Then, create a function that will create a `Dictionary` from your existing score data. It could looks something like this:

```
Function BuildDictionary() As Dictionary
    Dim dbWS As Worksheet
    Dim dbRange As Range
    Dim dbArea As Variant
    Set dbWS = ThisWorkbook.Sheets("MasterSheet")
    Set dbRange = dbWS.Range("A1:Z20")  'this should be dynamically calc'ed
    dbArea = dbRange                    'copied to memory array

    Dim dataDict As Dictionary
    Set dataDict = New Dictionary

    Dim i As Long
    For i = LBound(dbArea, 1) To UBound(dbArea, 1)
        Dim uniqueKey As String
        '--- combine several fields to create a unique identifier for each
        '    game:  Date+League+Teams
        uniqueKey = dbArea(i, 1) & "+" & dbArea(i, 2) & "+" & dbArea(i, 3)
        If Not dataDict.Exists(uniqueKey) Then
            dataDict.Add uniqueKey, i              'stores the row number
        End If
    Next i
    Set BuildDictionary = dataDict
End Function
```

Now, in your main logic you will take this created dictionary and use it to check if your new data already exists in your master sheet data:

```
Option Explicit

Sub ProcessNewData()
    Dim existingData As Dictionary
    Set existingData = BuildDictionary

    '--- loop over your new data sheet and create a "key" from the
    '    new data fields
    Dim newDataRange As Range
    Dim newDataArea As Variant
    Set newDataRange = ThisWorkbook.Sheets("NewDataSheet").Range("A1:Z20")
    newDataArea = newDataRange

    Dim i As Long
    For i = LBound(newDataArea, 1) To UBound(newDataArea, 1)
        Dim newKey As String
        '--- build a key using the same fields in the same format
        newKey = newDataArea(i, 1) & "+" & newDataArea(i, 2) & "+" & newDataArea(i, 3)
        If Not existingData.Exists(newKey) Then
            '--- add a new row of data to your master sheet data here and
            '    transfer from the newDataArea to the sheet
        End If
    Next dataRow
End Sub
```

Again, I haven't tested this code because I don't have access to your data formats, but it will hopefully push you farther down the path to a working solution.

Comment: Thank you very much! I shall experiment over the weekend!

Comment: Ok so gone through this and just want to replay how I think this works. I need to store the Function in it's own module and this will create a dictionary to reference later. I put the Sub in it's own module which does the moving of data. I then have two sheets: "MasterData" and "NewDataSheet". The challenge I have is the bit you left for me to complete :-) I guess now that I know that newKey doesn't exist I need to isolate that row and build a union range to copy across as in my original code? Going to try and think about code to do this...

Comment: Both of these subs can go in the same module. In fact, they can go in the same module as your own code. There's nothing magical about modules except as an organizing thing. If you do put subs/functions in separate modules and need to call them from another module, make sure they are tagged as `Public`, otherwise they can be `Private`. See [this](https://www.thespreadsheetguru.com/blog/2014/3/5/explaining-private-vs-public-declarations) for reference.

Comment: Bloody hell - I just surprised myself! Managed to figure it all out! Thanks you so so much for your help!!

Comment: Hi guys. Not sure if I should use a new thread but I have a question about a build on this. Now that I've created my updated "NewDataSheet" my next task is to push out data league by league to a series of individual league workbooks in a folder. I've found some looping code to do this and I'm fine to add the Sub above into it but the challenge is that I need to build a new Dictionary (via the Function) for each league sheet as I loop through them and the sheet name in the Function is static - how do I keep the Sub and the Function in line with one another?

Comment: To add more context the destination league workbook always has a sheet name that matches a league item in "NewDataSheet".

Comment: Think I might have figured it out - I simply need to define the league worksbook sheet name as a variable (Dim) in the Sub and I can reference this within the Function providing it's in the same module. Will try that.

Comment: That is exactly the path to take. Create as many variables as you need and make sure to use names that are descriptive to you and map to the solution you're building.